# Extract tex from href (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the TEXT from this HTML element:

`<a href="mailto:mail@1st-architects.com">mail@1st-architects.com</a>`

`all_profiles.find("a", {"???":"???"}).get_text(strip=True)`

Consider that I have a list of 1000 companies and each company has a href="mailto:mail@1st-architects.com" different.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine attribute = value css selector using starts with ^ and ends with $ operators to match on hrefs with specified substrings

```
emails = [i.text for i in all_profiles.select("[href^=mailto][href$='@1st-architects.com']")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

This code will print the text of all `<a>` with `href` as an email.

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''
<a href="mailto:mail@1st-architects.com">mail@1st-architects.com</a>
<a href="mailto:second_mail@2nd-architects.com">second_mail@2nd-architects.com</a>
<a href="#">Some Link</a>
<a href="mailto:mail@example.com">mail@example.com</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all('a', attrs= {'href': re.compile(r'^mailto:')})

for i in a:
    print(i.text.strip())
```

```
mail@1st-architects.com
second_mail@2nd-architects.com
mail@example.com
```